# unable to find ecdh parameters

Tags: openssl, curl, sles11

I'm working on an SLES 11 SP4 box and trying to connect to the host api.onedrive.com. Since a few days this connection is broken and returns with:

```
# curl https://api.onedrive.com
curl: (35) error:1408D13A:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:unable to find ecdh parameters
```

I suspect that the OpenSSL version shipped with SLES 11 cannot handle this connection.

Is there some backports repository or another way to make those connections work again?

Answer (score 0):

SLES 11 uses an old OpenSSL 0.9.8 and cannot handle TLS1.2 ciphers like ECDH (`openssl ciphers -v`). You can use:

```
curl --ciphers AES256-SHA https://api.onedrive.com
```